# VS2010 Silverlight templates not compiling: "WebContextBase is not defined". What's going on? How do I get this working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, default

I'm beginning my first explorations into Silverlight RIAs and EF4, but I can't get a project to run right off the templates that ship with VS2010 SP1.

Bear in mind here that what I've done is to install a brand new Windows 7 VM, and then I immediately installed LightSwitch Beta 2. Following that, I added VS2010 Premium, and applied Service Pack 1 to that.

The client portion of the Template app is kicking off three warnings and two errors; the details are posted below. It's looking for a `WebContextBase` class that it can't find, in code that it generated into Web.g.vb (and Web.g.cs) files. So far this project is entirely generated off the solution template; I haven't added a single line of code to what VS2010 generated.

I've since gotten EF4 to work fine in WinForms projects and Light Switch projects.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

---

> ------ Build started: Project: EF4Test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
>   ------ C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EF4Test\EF4Test\Generated_Code\EF4Test.Web.g.vb(21)
>   : warning BC40056: Namespace or type
>   specified in the Imports
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices'
>   doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the
>   namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member.
>   Make sure the imported element name
>   doesn't use any aliases.
>   C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EF4Test\EF4Test\Generated_Code\EF4Test.Web.g.vb(22)
>   : warning BC40056: Namespace or type
>   specified in the Imports
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client'
>   doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the
>   namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member.
>   Make sure the imported element name
>   doesn't use any aliases.
>   C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EF4Test\EF4Test\Generated_Code\EF4Test.Web.g.vb(23)
>   : warning BC40056: Namespace or type
>   specified in the Imports
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices'
>   doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the
>   namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member.
>   Make sure the imported element name
>   doesn't use any aliases.
>   C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EF4Test\EF4Test\Generated_Code\EF4Test.Web.g.vb(34)
>   : error BC30002: Type 'WebContextBase'
>   is not defined.
>   C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EF4Test\EF4Test\Generated_Code\EF4Test.Web.g.vb(65)
>   : error BC30451: 'WebContextBase' is
>   not declared. It may be inaccessible
>   due to its protection level.

---

Comment: I answered but I'm not sure it was correct, what template did you use to create your project?  If you're trying to create a RIA services class lib. http://www.blogs.victorero.com/2010/04/20/CreatingASilverlightApplicationWithAWCFRIAServicesClassLibrary.aspx

Comment: It was the Silverlight Application template, which starts a configuration wizard. I chose "Host the Silverlight Application in a new web site" and took defaults from there, which selects "ASP.NET Web Application Project". I also checked the RIA services box.

Comment: I'd try installing the LightSwitch beta in the exact order required which is after installing VS.Net 2010 SP1. There seem to be a few people having issues if it's not installed exactly as documented, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/lightswitchgeneral/thread/24fc9bd6-b0f4-421e-a439-704a444bc564.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [LightSwitch Beta 2 Readme](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=211075)

There are few know issues with the LightSwitch. From the steps you have described to setup your system I would *guess* that the problem could be because

> "2.1.1 Visual Studio 2010 users or
>   Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta1 users
>   must install Visual Studio 2010 SP1
>   before installing Visual Studio
>   LightSwitch Beta2"

You should try uninstalling LightSwitch Beta2 and then reinstall, and let us know if you get the same error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought I had SP1 with the full install of Beta 2 LightSwitch on a fresh Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I removed LightSwitch, removed SP1, removed VS2010. then, reinstalled VS2010, applied SP1, and left LightSwitch uninstalled. The error persists. Same thing.

Comment: @Rob Perkins: I see you accepted the answer at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/222849/536170.aspx, did that not solve the problem?

Comment: In point of fact I didn't accept that answer, which I thought was brief, trite, and dismissive. OF COURSE it needs the thing it's missing. I don't know what MS is playing at on that forum.

Comment: Well, I can't explain it completely, but now it seems to be working OK. You got me on the right track here and I was able to fix it, so the award goes to you and the answer tag as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Include this reference..
 System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices

Comment: Include it where? In the generated file where the error is occurring at compile time? If this were as easy as a google search, I wouldn't have written up the question for StackOverflow! -1